# CMake Error while building VTK 'INSTALL' project

Tags: c++, build, cmake, doxygen, vtk

I generated VTK 8.1.1 VS2015 solution by CMake, and when I build 'ALL_BUILD' project, it works well.
but when I try building 'INSTALL' project, the error followed occurs:

```
 -- Installing: C:/Program Files/VTK/share/doc/vtk-8.1/doxygen/doc_index.stop
2>  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/VTK/share/doc/vtk-8.1/doxygen/doc_readme.txt
2>  CMake Error at Utilities/Doxygen/cmake_install.cmake:60 (file):
2>    file INSTALL cannot find
2>    "C:/workspace/VTK_build/Utilities/Doxygen/doc/html".
2>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
2>    cmake_install.cmake:226 (include)
2>
```

I do run vs2015 as administrator.

and I have checked that there doesn't have a folder called doc under 'Doxygen' indeed.

please tell me why does this error happen? did I config something wrong?

and what should I do now?

**update 1 :**
I delete the sentence in file 'cmake_install.cmake' that uses `/Doxygen/doc/html`.

It is compiled successfully, but I don't know if there would have some thing wrong in the future.

**update 2 :**
The problem is solved. It just need to build `DoxygenDoc` separately and `/Doxygen/doc/` and some other files will be generated. For more details please see comments below.

Comment: presumably you don't have permission to write to program files, are you running as administrator?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes I do.

Comment: I see 2 types of paths "C:/Program Files/..." and "C:/workspace/" not sure what the second is but it looks like a directory where you build the sources before the install, looks like the documentation has not been build. Do you have doxygen installed on your computer (and graphviz dot)?

Comment: @albert yes, I installed both doxygen and graphviz. About VTK, there are 3 directories with different content at different positions. First directory has VTK source code and CMake files at 'C:/'. Second one which has generated VS solution by CMake and output of compiling 'ALL_BUILD' project are placed at C:/workspace/. The third directory has the output of 'INSTALL' project and are placed at 'C:/Program Files/' automatically. And the error occurred when compiling the 'INSTALL' project.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the build procedure, but is the doxygen documentation build or is there another target (not in ALL_BUILD) that builds the documentation? Is there anywhere after the build a directory doc/html ? In the CMake configuration there is (as far as I can see athttps://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build#Configure_VTK_with_CMake) an item `BUILD_DOCUMENTATION`, is this checked? (when not then the installation procedure of VTK has a small bug in my opinion)

Comment: @albert Yes, there is a project called 'DoxygenDoc', and after I compile it, the folder 'Doxygen/doc' and some other files are generated. Thank you！

Comment: Good that you solved the problem. When I understand it correctly the `DoxygenDoc` is not part of `ALL_BUILD`, which makes sense as you don't want always rebuild the documentation during the development. Did you check the dependencies between the `install` target and the building of the documentation as here there might be a problem (i.e. conditionally install the documentation?) in the CMake files. Maybe also open an issue with VTK pointing to the problems you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the documentation has not been build as its target `DoxygenDoc`  is not part off the `ALL_BUILD` target (which makes sense as you don't want always rebuild the documentation during the development).
Building the documentation creates the required directories and makes it possible to install the documentation.
Note also that the `BUILD_DOCUMENTATION` in CMake has to be set to be able to build the documentation.